# Best practice for SWV and DAD Cisco 9400

Tags: cisco, network-core, stackwise

I have 2 Cisco 9404R chassis. In each chassis I have:

- 1 x 48p 10 Gig ethernet -> slot 1
- 1 x 9400X-sup-2 -> slot 2 & 3.

I know that I should configure Stackwise Virtual between only 1 SUP module per chassis and plan to use ports 5-8.

Am I correct? Which solution should I choose? At least I want 2 interfaces in SWV in each chassis. Should I also configure DAD -link between the SUP's?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, configure StackWise Virtual with [Dual-Active Detection](https://community.cisco.com/t5/switching/c9500-swv-benefits-of-configuring-multiple-dual-active-detection/td-p/4056244) (DAD).

If your links are switched with STP, DAD offers the benefit mentioned in the CCO cisco.com community link, above:

> When ALL of your SVLs are down, and there is no existence of DAD. Both switches will run separately, and your MECs might turn into Error Disable due to STP Mis-configuration guard.